# Expand All and Collapse All for questions and Answers in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am developing question and answers where the Q&A are in v-for. All have a show answer and hide answer where we can expand and collapse every single answer and also have the collapse all /Expand all buttons.

The functionality for expand all /collapse all and also show answer /hide answer are working fine but the issue is when I click on expand all and then try to hide one answer, all the answers are getting closed.

Please let me know how do I fix it.

```js
<div v-for="(techQuest,index) in questionList.questions" v-bind:value="techQuest" :key="index">
    <div class="tech-qa-question">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color:#2b91ca;padding-right:2px;" v-show="!techQuest.expanded"
            :id="'showAns_'+index" v-on:click="showAnswer(index)">
            <img border="0" src="/images/icons/gray-plus.png"></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color:#2b91ca;padding-right:2px;" v-show="techQuest.expanded"
            :id="'hideAns_'+index" v-on:click="hideAnswer(index)">
            <img border="0" src="/images/icons/gray-minus.png"></a>
        <span style="color: #007185;"> {{techQuest.question}}</span>
    </div>
    <div v-if="(show && showIndex === index) || expand" style="overflow:auto;padding:1rem;padding-left: 30px;">
        <div v-html="techQuest.answer.answer"></div>
        <div class="tech-qa-adc">
            By Member
        </div>
        <table class="tech-qa-ballot">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Did you find this answer helpful?</td>
                <td v-if="(!techQuest.voteDisable && techQuest.index === index)">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" v-on:click="castVote(techQuest.answer.answerId,'1',index,1)">
                        <i class='fas fa-solid fa-thumbs-up' style="color:#0d72c2;padding-right:10px;padding-left:5px;"
                            aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" v-on:click="castVote(techQuest.answer.answerId,'-1',index,1)">
                        <i class='fas fa-solid fa-thumbs-down' style="color:#0d72c2" aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
                </td>
                <td v-else>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="disable">
                        <i class='fas fa-solid fa-thumbs-up' style="color:darkgrey;padding-right:10px;padding-left:5px;"
                            aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="disable">
                        <i class='fas fa-solid fa-thumbs-down' style="color:darkgrey" aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
                </td>
                <td style="color: green;" v-show="(showThanks && showIndex=== index)">
                    Thanks for your feedback!
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div v-else style="display: none"></div>
    <hr aria-hidden="true" style="border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;border-bottom-width: 0;background-color: transparent;">
</div>


// js part:

    showAnswer: function(value) {
    this.showThanks = false;
    this.showQuestThanks = false;
    this.questionList.questions.forEach(show => {
      show['expanded'] = false;
    });
    this.show = true;  
    this.expand = false;
    this.showIndex = value;
    this.questionList.questions[value].expanded = true;
   },
   hideAnswer: function(value) {
    if(!this.expand){
      console.log("Inside the this.expand loop" + this.expand);
    this.questionList.questions.forEach(hide => {
      hide['expanded'] = false;
    });}
    this.show = false;  
    this.expand = false;
    this.showIndex = null;
    this.questionList.questions[value].expanded = false;
   },
  collapseAll: function() {
     this.questionList.questions.forEach(collapse => {
      collapse['expanded'] = false;
    });
    this.show = false;  
    this.expand = false;
    this.showIndex = null;
  },
  expandAll: function() {
      this.questionList.questions.forEach(expand => {
      expand['expanded'] = true;
    });
    this.expand = true;
    this.show = true;
    },
```

Comment: Not sure how do I format the code here.

Comment: have edited the code